# What is the formula for this air waybill non arithmetic sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let's say, The first eight terms of the numbers are given: 100, 111, 122, 133, 144, 155, 166, 170,...

So, when the last digit is between 0 to 5, add 11, and only when last digit is 6, add 4.

How can I find the formula to find out what is ***nth*** term in this sequence?
(given the first term can be any number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that
$$
a_n = a_1 - 7 b_1 + 4(n-1) + 7 \left\lfloor \frac{6(n+b_1)}{7} \right\rfloor
$$
will do the trick.  Here, $a_1$ is the first number in the sequence, $b_1 = a_1 \bmod 10$ is the last digit of $a_1$, and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ gives the largest integer less than $x$.

Note that this equation does not work if $b_1 = $ 7, 8, or 9, but according to your specifications these cases will never occur anyhow.  Still, if you're programming this into a computer or something, you should probably do some exception checking before applying this equation.

Comment: this won't work when $a_1$ is 133, first number could be any number with the last digit of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: @joegreentea:  Fixed.

Comment: yes, last digit won't be 7, 8, or 9. It works now, checked the numbers against thousands of records. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let us call the first number $a_0$, and let $a$ be the last digit of $a_0$.

Your sequence goes like this: six out of seven times you add $11$, the seventh time you add only 4.

This is the same as saying that you add every time an 11, and subtract one time in seven a 7.

If there was no subtraction, the formula would be $a_1+11(n-1)$.

To subtract a 7 every seventhth step, you can use $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{7} \rfloor \times 7$. The problem is that this is subtracting every 8th step, you want your counter to start at step $a+1$ (as last digit being 0 is considered the first step). This means, you have to shift your count to start at $a+1$.

**Answer:**
$$a_n=11(n-1)-  \lfloor \frac{n+a}{7} \rfloor \times 7$$

Comment: this works, except that $a_1$ must be calculated beforehand.